# how can we get E-mail receiving notification in android

Tags: android

how can we get E-mail receiving notification in android

Comment: hai shripal iam also doing same thing can u please help me...i also want to get email notification in android can u please provide the codee...iam trying from past 2days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same with me also
can we get info by registering a content observer like this

ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        m_EmailObserver = new EmailObserver(this);
        contentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, true, m_EmailObserver);

in email observer we can read email recieved 
is it not correct way to get email notifiactions

Comment: hi If u don't mind please elabrate u'r answer with sample.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "E-mail receiving notification in android", any more than there is "E-mail receiving notification" in Windows. Email is received by applications, not by the operating system. Individual email applications may or may not send out broadcast Intents advertising the receipt of email -- you would have to contact the developers of those applications to find out.

Comment: there is an action for sms receiver android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED so,is their any such receiver for E-mail receiver?

Comment: @shripal: No. Again, the operating system has nothing to do with email.